# Does Google app engine supports JDBC?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdbc, crud

I have heard the Google App Engine[java] do not support JDBC and Hibernate. Is it true?
If yes then how do we access the database in Google App Engine.

Also, is there any [basic] sample application which can help me understand how to perform CRUD operations in GAE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JDBC and Hibernate are not supported: http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/web/will-it-play-in-app-engine

I'm currently learning app engine too.   Here's some resources and projects that have been helpful:

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/overview.html

http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java

Springsource Tool Suite is shipped with the Google Plugin for Eclipse (GPE):
http://www.springsource.com/products/sts

A non-trivial web app example (spring mvc/gwt/jsf + JDO + spring IOC, service layer, DAOs, DTOs, test suite):
http://code.google.com/p/swagswap/

Answer (score 2):

Google uses their own type of Datastore for GAE apps.  Here is there documentation for how it works: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/overview.html.  That page has examples of how it works.

Answer (score 2):

AppEngine doesn't use a relational database. You should really read the docs about how AppEngine works, starting with this [Java-oriented overview of AppEngine](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/overview.html).

AppEngine delivers on its scalability promise by leveraging Google-style infrastructure. If you're looking to use a more traditional stack, you'll probably be better off with [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's true. JDBC drivers won't work there, as long as GAE datastore is not based on RDBMS (it's rather some kind of NoSQL big-table storage). 
If you want to work with GAE storage via ActiveRecord ORM (Hibernate-like), you may be interested in JPA or JDO - the both are supported. Alternatively, you can directly use low-level API.
For more information you may refer to [Datastore Java API Overview](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/overview.html).

Answer (score 0):

> Storing data in a scalable web application can be tricky.

You have to use their datastore API.
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/usingdatastore.html

Answer (score 0):

There is an early-stage 3rd party project to build a JDBC driver for the App Engine nonrel datastore:

http://www.jiql.org/xwiki/bin/view/Main/